# Request for member 'something' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c

So hi guys, im on colleague and i have to do a program in c to sort simulate a system of tickets in a reparation store.

I made this like basically every type of ticket has a structure.

this is an example.

```
typedef struct reparacao
typedef struct  entrega
{
char servico_ent;
int numtick_ent;
int dia_entrada_ent;
int mes_entrada_ent;
int ano_entrada_ent;
int hora_entrada_ent;
int min_entrada_ent;
int hora_atend_ent;
int min_atend_ent;  
int balcao_ent;
char cond_ent[100];
float valor_pagar;
};
entrega entrega1[100];
```

and then i write to get the time

```
`time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
printf("%d-%d-%d %d:%d\n", tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min);
// verificar se o horário está entre as 8H e as 22H
if(tm.tm_hour<8 || tm.tm_hour>=22) 
{
    printf("\nNao pode recolher ticket. Horario: 8:00h-21:59h\n\n");
}else
    {
    //Guardar dados no vetor
        printf("Ticket numero %d\n\n", natend_ent);
        entrega1[j].numtick_ent = natend_ent;
        entrega1[j].servico_ent = 'Entrega';
        entrega1[j].dia_entrada_ent = tm.tm_mday;
        entrega1[j].mes_entrada_ent = tm.tm_mon+1;
        entrega1[j].ano_entrada_ent = tm.tm_year + 1900;
        entrega1[j].hora_entrada_ent = tm.tm_hour;
        entrega1[j].min_entrada_ent = tm.tm_min;
        natend_ent++;
        j++;
    }`
```

What can it is causing the error "Request for member 'blablabla' in something not a structure or union"?

Comment: What is "it"? You need to explain what outcome you expect and what outcome you observe.

Comment: `entrega1[j].servico_ent = 'Entrega';` is wrong because `servicio_ent` is a single character but you want to assign multiple characters.

Comment: Maybe use `char servico_ent[32];` and then `strcpy(entrega1[j].servico_ent, "Entrega");`

Comment: Missing `#include <time.h>`.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: Copying the exact error message instead of "error something something blablabla" may better help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `entrega1` as an array whose elements are of type `entrega`, but the code presented does not define type `entrega`, and in particular, that identifier is not defined as representing a structure type.  Your compiler ought to be complaining about that, too.  It is often best to start handling warnings and errors from the top, because it is not uncommon for bad code in one place to cause multiple errors.

Specifically in this case, your `typedef` keywords do nothing because you are not declaring any identifier for them to apply to.  Perhaps you have the relatively common misunderstanding that `typedef` is used for defining new types, especially structure types.  It is not.  It is for defining *aliases* for types.  The type you *have* declared is `struct entrega` (the `struct` keyword is part of the type name), and you may use that everywhere.  If you want to be able to omit the `struct` part, then the correct way to use a typedef for that world be:

```
typedef struct entrega {
    char servico_ent;
    /* ... other members ... */
    float valor_pagar;
} entrega;
```

Equivalently, you could separate the typedef from the structure definition:

```
struct entrega {
    char servico_ent;
    /* ... other members ... */
    float valor_pagar;
};

typedef struct entrega entrega;
```

The latter is perhaps more instructive than the former.  It may also be instructive that you are permitted to swap the order of the `typedef` and the structure definition.